# When running simulations in Veins, can one dump the Console Output into a file

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am currently running Simulations in Veins and/or Artery.

- Is there an easy way (thats perhaps I just didn't find because I'm blind/stupid) to dump the Output created in the Console into a file, apart from running it slower than express mode and then using copy/paste?
- Can I create these data while still running in express-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: if by 'console output' you mean the event log, then yes you can, but no you shouldn't, for exactly the reason you mention: express mode disables this output.
The recommended way to collect data from your simulation is by recording it using "statistics", see also [this](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part5.html) page of the OMNeT++ tutorial.

You can log this information using the `record-eventlog=true` option in your `omnetpp.ini` (as described in more detail [in the manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:eventlog:configuration)), but this produces huge files for veins and artery. This is because the event log is used more as a logging system. The best way to think of it is as debug output and development support: to quickly figure out why something isn't working correctly. I tried to (ab)use this feature for logging data -- please, save yourself the immense pains and use the statistics module.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid, that would be the case. However that brings me to a follow up problem. For some reason Artery does not create a vector output file in the results folder. `**.vector-recording = true` is set in any omnetpp.ini I can find. As of now only the .sca-file appears in the results folder of artery.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you there exactly, since I don't know whether there are any events emitted or vectors recorded by default. Just grepping through my current veins project reveals that only `recordScalar` is used, not `recordVector`, so it might be that you're not actually recording any data in your simulation

Comment: if you're not sure how to properly collect vectors, I'd suggest reading the manual in this regard, and if necessary ask another question (someone else may be able to provide more expertise)

Comment: As far as I know, recording Vectors happens via `cOutVector` of which there are numerous calls in the Inet Code and the Veins Source Code in the 'extern' folder. But yeah, I'll probably ask another Question. Thanks again!

Comment: Right, of course, my mistake :) one other thing you could try is looking at the sca output and see whether it contains information pertaining to `vector-recording`, though I'm not sure whether those options are recorded off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Easiest way, From top bar, go to: Run > Run Configuration > Common tab > scroll down to output and select the name and the location of the output file.

Downside, each time you want to run a different application, it over writes the previous one that was created, so don't forget to back it up before you run a different simulation.

Good luck.